# Creating 2 quarter-sheet sized booklet on single sheet of paper

Tags: printing

I need to create/print a booklet that is 1/4 size of a sheet of 8.5" x 11" paper. From this page, [How can I print a booklet from a pdf file?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3832/how-can-i-print-a-booklet-from-a-pdf-file), I know I how to create the booklet. But this is larger than I want.

Because this is just a quarter size sheet of paper, I can print two copies of the booklet on a single sheet of paper. I need to know how to automagically make this happen; stack one on top of the other.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use Table settings and cells, e.g. in Word
2. Use Pages as layout program able to integrate texts generated in Word or elsewhere

in that manner, you can easily specify the printing fields.